# Evenly distribute contents of array to a number of rows

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I'm currently working with Google Apps Script and wish to distribute an array (eg. `['MP', 'JE', 'MC', 'GP', 'CZ', 'DM', 'MD']`) as evenly as possible against a number of spreadsheet rows.

Say there are 21 rows, and I'm using the above array of length `7`. I would want to iterate through each entry of the array and output each entry 3 times.

Seemingly simple enough to do:

```
var exampleArr = ['MP', 'JE', 'MC', 'GP', 'CZ', 'DM', 'MD'];

function distributeArr(arr, rowLen){
  for (i = 0; n = arr.length, i < n; i++){
    for (r = 0; r < rowLen / n; r++) {
      console.log(arr[i]);
    }
  }
}

distributeArr(exampleArr, 21);
```

But when the two numbers aren't evenly divisible, it'll round up to the nearest match. What's a good way to deal with this while keeping the distribution of array items to rows as even as possible?

Comment: What's your desired outcome when the number of rows is not divisible by the number of length of the array? Say 21 rows and length of array is 8?

Comment: @EJ2015 Perhaps something like each entry is output 3 times except the last 3, which only get two results each. Basically, I'm attempting to assign out task responsibilities using initials as evenly as possible. Sometimes staff will get a little more work than others, but over time it'd even out.

Comment: Well over the time it might not even out if the last few guys always get the same amount or less.

Comment: @EJ2015 The array goes through a Fisher-Yates Shuffle before assignment, so I'm not overly concerned about a bias towards the end of the array. But I'm open to any ideas. Just not able to wrap my head around a good solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to get the remainder and distribute it to the staff.

```
function distributeArr(staffArr, numOfTasks) {
  var numOfStaff = staffArr.length;
  var extra = numOfTasks % numOfStaff;
  var taskPerPerson = parseInt(numOfTasks / numOfStaff);
  var assignment = staffArr.map(function(e) {
    if (staffArr.indexOf(e) < extra) {
        return [e, taskPerPerson + 1];
      }
      else {
        return [e, taskPerPerson];
      }
  });

  assignment.forEach(function(arr) {
    // create arr[1] rows for staff arr[0]
  });
}

var staffArr = ['MP', 'JE', 'MC'];
distributeArr(staffArr, 7); //assignment: [["MP", 3], ["JE", 2], ["MC", 2]]
distributeArr(staffArr, 6); //assignment: [["MP", 2], ["JE", 2], ["MC", 2]]
distributeArr(staffArr, 0); //assignment: [["MP", 0], ["JE", 0], ["MC", 0]]
distributeArr(staffArr, 1); //assignment: [["MP", 1], ["JE", 0], ["MC", 0]]
```

Comment: Looks great! Can you go into a little detail about what's going on in the anonymous function with `var assignment`?

Comment: You divide `numOfTasks` with `numOfStaff`, and you get `taskPerPerson` plus `extra` (the remainder). So the anonymous function just adds one more task to the first `extra` number of staff to distribute the tasks evenly, then the rest will have `taskPerPerson` of tasks.